# how to use autofilter in vba

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I can't find the answer even if I search.
I want all search results including keyword.
However, the results show only part of it.
The code below is the result of the 3 hour.. .

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim T As String
 Dim rngArea As Range

 With Target
  If .Address = "$CH$3" Then
   If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set rngArea = Me.Range("A5").CurrentRegion
     T = .Value
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then
      If Me.FilterMode = True Then
       Me.ShowAllData: rngArea.AutoFilter
       End If
     Else
     
      rngArea.Columns(66).AutoFilter 1, "=*" & T & "*", , , 0

    End If
    .Select
   End If
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this too, and even when setting the field type to Text, it doesn't work. After that, I tried adding a letter in front of the data (to force it to be a string) and this worked. Somehow Excel still treats the data as numbers if you don't add at least one letter in the data.

If you're able to add a column that contains ="a" & A5, then you can perform the Autofilter on that and it should work (make sure that that column and the input field are set to Type Text). Hacky solution though

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience!!